# Replace pointer arithmetic with std::span

Tags: c++

I have the following code that uses pointer arithmetic and would like to replace it using `std::span` (or, I suppose, `gsl::span`). The code iterates over a number of pixels, each represented by 4 contiguous bytes, and updates their blue and green colours.

```
auto* row = (uint8_t*)buffer->data;
for (auto y = 0; y < buffer->height; ++y) {
    auto* pixel = (uint32_t*)row;
    for (auto x = 0; x < buffer->width; ++x) {
        auto blue = x + blueOffset;
        auto green = y + greenOffset;
        *pixel++ = ((green << 8) | blue);
    }
    row += buffer->pitch;
}
```

`buffer->data` is a `void*` returned from a call to Windows `VirtualAlloc(...)` function.

How can this code be written to use safe, modern C++, such as `std::span`, as suggested by the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#probounds-bounds-safety-profile) and [Moderns C++](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-bounds-safety)?

Comment: Well, considering the type punning and the unconstrained bit manipulations of signed types, I don't think that introducing `std::span` is going to get this snippet much more "modern". What transformation do you want to apply to those pixels, is it a linear color transition? What are the dimensions of the image and what values do `blueOffset` and `greenOffset` have?

Answer (score 0):

This compiles with each of C++20, gsl and gsl-lite. As you didn't provide a reproducible example I didn't test or benchmark this solution.

```cpp
    auto const my_span = span{
        reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(buffer->data),
        buffer->height * buffer->pitch};
    constexpr auto size_ratio = sizeof(uint32_t) / sizeof(uint8_t); // 4
    auto const uint8_width = size_ratio * buffer->width;

    auto row_offset = 0UL;
    auto row = my_span.subspan(row_offset, buffer->width);
    for (auto y = 0; y < buffer->height; ++y) {
        auto const pixels = span{
            reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(row.data()),
            buffer->width};
        auto pixel = pixels.begin();
        for (auto x = 0; x < buffer->width; ++x) {
            auto const blue = x + blueOffset;
            auto const green = y + greenOffset;
            *pixel++ = ((green << 8) | blue);
        }
        row_offset += buffer->pitch;
        row = my_span.subspan(row_offset, uint8_width);
    }
```

Obviously using spans here doesn't necessarily make the code easier to read due to interpreting the same memory both as `uint8_t` and `uint32_t`. The spans should still give more safety.

The code could be made easier to read by providing more members or member functions in the struct which is pointed at by `buffer`. E.g. member functions could provide you with the needed subspans or at least with `uint8_width`. As this wasn't asked, I didn't touch that struct here. It might be given by a library, but one could still write a wrapper in that case.

Comment: Thanks. I got this to compile with some tweaks. Your answer helped me understand span and get there. QueryPerformanceCounter has this running between 18ms and 40ms, compared to a pretty constant 3ms for the original pointer arithmetic. Any suggestions, or does that warrant a separate question?

Comment: @amb85 I don't see a lot of room for improvement in the code without usiing less spans, which isn't the purpose of this. Could you go into detail on which implementation you used for benchmarking? Especially it would be good to know if the compiled code actually checked the limits at each `*pixel++` and at subspan creation (e.g. check by letting the loops run too far). If these boundary checks are performed it isn't surprising that it takes that much longer, I guess. If they are only performed in debug mode and not in the binary you are benchmarking, I don't know where it comes from.